# How to show delete button on top of the UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview

Please help me. I am phasing a problem, show a delete button on top of the view.

[image]

Without using bezier path showing like this

When i use bezier path is showing like this

[image]

how i can show the button.

This is the code i am using

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
[view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view1.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft| UIRectCornerTopRight                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
// Create the shape layer and set its path
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = view1.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
// Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the image view's layer
view1.layer.mask = maskLayer;

[self.view addSubview:view1];

UIButton *bt1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[bt1 setTitle:@"D" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bt1 setFrame:CGRectMake(87, -10, 25, 25)];
[view1 addSubview:bt1];
```

please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modifying the layer with your UIBezierPath, you're saying  Hey, on this view, show only that's in the UIBezierPath. So it's normal that your button got cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always add the button in your superview depending of the view's position.

What @Larme said is true ,when you're making a view you're masking all the subviews that view has.

In case you don't want to do that just enter in your view's drawRect and draw there transparent corners to achieve the same effect.